# Customize a PHP theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, themes

I have a simple question: I have downloaded a PHP theme on PremiumPress and I would like to customize the theme and show it on my browser the different page, there is a way to make it?
And is it possible to convert the PHP file in Javascript?

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can modify your theme as you wish. Usualy you want to use child theme to modify your stuff but in your case since its going to be js and i guess the theme is not written in js i would recommend writing your own theme over editing theme.

Answer (score 0):

If you customize, it's better to create `child-theme`; otherwise, if you directly change the original theme, you will lose all your changes in the next update of the theme.